# azure webapp do not appear on visual studio publisher

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure

I would like to create a project on visual studio then publish it on azure, but my azure app does not appear on my subscription on visual studio. I don't know what to do. Here are some pictures:

[image: azure screenshot]

[image: visual studio screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

My visual studio has always done this as well.

Instead when I select to publish I select Custom and setup a Web Deploy to push to Azure. You will need to download your publish profile info from the Azure portal to get the Server, Sitename, Username, Password etc. This will create a local publish profile that you can use over and over again.